# Swagger-Ui-Express Not loading UI in production

Tags: node.js, express, swagger

I have an express application with swagger-ui-express 4.1.4 integrated.
It works fine in the local environment.
On production, it stops working and gives the below error in the image[image]

Here is how I am serving the docs
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUI.serve, swaggerUI.setup(swaggerSpec));

when I push the code to server and serve using nginx it breaks

Comment: Are those failing requests? You've given us almost nothing to go on

Comment: just a hunch.... is the swagger installed as a part of dev dependencies??